# SQL Server 2016 Install entering Single User Mode

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-server-2016, sql-server-2016

We have a problem which happens on approx 1 in 5 installs of SQL 2016 on Win 2016 (using amazon EC2).  The install fails and seems to be that the SQL Server enters single user mode whilst the install is taking place.  I have the full logs, but have attached the part of the bootstrap log where it happens.

Seems to get approx 3/4 of the way through before it happens.  Any ideas!?

```
(01) 2017-09-20 09:21:06 Slp: Connection string: Data Source=\\.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Connect Timeout=300;Network Library=dbnmpntw;Application Name=SqlSetup
(01) 2017-09-20 09:21:06 Slp: Sco: Connection error code from SqlException is : 18461
(01) 2017-09-20 09:21:06 ACE: ERROR: Unable to connect to SQL Server Engine. Exception: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException: Login failed for user 'CORP\EC2AMAZ-536HENV$'. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'CORP\EC2AMAZ-536HENV$'. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlScriptExecution.GetConnection()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlScriptExecution.Connect()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlScriptExecution.Connect()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Agent.SqlScriptExecutionWrapper.PrepareScriptConnection()'
(01) 2017-09-20 09:21:06 Slp: Configuration action failed for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during timing ConfigRC and scenario ConfigRC.
(01) 2017-09-20 09:21:06 Slp: Login failed for user 'CORP\EC2AMAZ-536HENV$'. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time.
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today.  I uninstalled SQL Server and re-ran the install.  Prior to doing that I did notice in the SQL Server Config Manager that the DB Engine was indeed installed and running, which I thought was odd since the UI gave me a red "X" next to the DB engine install.

On the second install attempt I received the same error but noticed a "Retry" option.  I selected Retry and everything finished successfully.